# Akka actor construction in Play! framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka

I am playing with the Play! framework and I wanted to create a factory called Services which will create new actors. I have this so far

```
class UserRegistration extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case "foo" => "bar"
  }
}

object UserRegistration {
  val path: String = "user/registration"
}


object Services {
  val system = ActorSystem("Services")

  def apply[A<:Actor]: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[A], A.path)
}
```

And I wanted to create and pass messages to actors like this:

```
Services[UserRegistration] ? "hello"
```

but I get errors of the type `could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type ClassManifest[A]`. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong here? And if this is a valid construction in general (a best practice). I am pretty new in Scala and still learning stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

senia's answer works too, but if you want to specify a common path for each type of actor, you need a second implicit parameter(the first being the `ClassManifest` so that you can specify a path for each type of actor. Keep in mind that actor names have to be unique though, so you have to add something to that path.

First you define a class that holds the Path:

```
case class Path(value:String)
```

Then you define an implicit value in the companion object of your actor class:

```
object SomeActor {
  implicit val path = Path("SomeActor")
}
```

Finally you modify the apply method to take an implicit class manifest as well as an implicit path.

```
def apply[A<:Actor](implicit cm:ClassManifest[A], path:Path[A]): ActorRef = 
  system.actorOf(Props[A], path.value + someIndex)
```

Comment: Thanks Kim for your thorough answer!I read about unique actor names but everyone who creates Actors uses one name per "service". Do I have to use some kind of UUID together with the path? Say that I want to create an actor for a UserRegistration service, the path "user/registration" doesn't suffice?

Comment: If there is only one such actor, of course "user/registration" is sufficient. If not, you should use "user/registration" + uuid.

Answer (score 1):

Method `apply` of object `Props` implicitly takes parameter of type `ClassManifest[T]`.

```
apply [T <: Actor] (implicit arg0: ClassManifest[T])
```

You have to add such parameter into your method:

```
def apply[A<:Actor : ClassManifest]: ActorRef = system.actorOf(Props[A])
```

Comment: That still won't work because of `A.path`. One can't call methods on types. So he will probably need another implicit argument for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot senia! Well this solved my initial error with the ClassManifest but now i get `not found: value A` on the A.path call. I suspect that I cannot call methods on A because A is a type :/ (As @KimStebel pointed out).. How can I solve this?

Comment: @Gerry: You can use method `actorOf (props: Props): ActorRef` or add parameter `name: String` to your `apply` method.